# How to print layout builder sections inside of a twig file in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8, drupal-views, kint

I am looking to set up a three column grid in Layout Builder to be printed within a bootstrap col-md-4 div. I am wondering how I can print each column within its own bootstrap column.

My main thing is I dont understand how to print out the contents of the array. When I use kint it shows:

```
(
    [#settings] => Array
        (
            [label] => 
            [column_widths] => 33-34-33
        )

    [#layout] => stdClass Object
        (
            [__CLASS__] => Drupal\Core\Layout\LayoutDefinition
            [deriver:protected] => 
            [label:protected] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [__CLASS__] => Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup
                    [translatedMarkup:protected] => 
                    [options:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [stringTranslation:protected] => 
                    [string:protected] => Three column
                    [arguments:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [description:protected] => 
            [category:protected] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [__CLASS__] => Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup
                    [translatedMarkup:protected] => 
                    [options:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [stringTranslation:protected] => 
                    [string:protected] => Columns: 3
                    [arguments:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [template:protected] => layout--threecol-section
            [templatePath:protected] => core/modules/layout_builder/layouts/threecol_section
            [theme_hook:protected] => layout__threecol_section
            [path:protected] => core/modules/layout_builder/layouts/threecol_section
            [library:protected] => layout_builder/threecol_section
            [icon:protected] => 
            [icon_map:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => first
                            [1] => second
                            [2] => third
                        )

                )

            [regions:protected] => Array
                (
                    [first] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [__CLASS__] => Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup
                                    [translatedMarkup:protected] => 
                                    [options:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [context] => layout_region
                                        )

                                    [stringTranslation:protected] => 
                                    [string:protected] => First
                                    [arguments:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [second] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [__CLASS__] => Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup
                                    [translatedMarkup:protected] => 
                                    [options:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [context] => layout_region
                                        )

                                    [stringTranslation:protected] => 
                                    [string:protected] => Second
                                    [arguments:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [third] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [__CLASS__] => Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup
                                    [translatedMarkup:protected] => 
                                    [options:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [context] => layout_region
                                        )

                                    [stringTranslation:protected] => 
                                    [string:protected] => Third
                                    [arguments:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [default_region:protected] => second
            [additional:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [id:protected] => layout_threecol_section
            [class:protected] => Drupal\layout_builder\Plugin\Layout\ThreeColumnLayout
            [provider:protected] => layout_builder
            [config_dependencies:protected] => Array
                (
                    [module] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => layout_builder
                        )

                )

        )

    [#theme] => layout__threecol_section
    [#attached] => Array
        (
            [library] => Array
                (
                    [0] => layout_builder/threecol_section
                )

        )

    [#attributes] => Array
        (
            [class] => Array
                (
                    [0] => layout
                    [1] => layout--threecol-section
                    [2] => layout--threecol-section--33-34-33
                )

        )

    [#cache] => Array
        (
            [tags] => Array
                (
                )

            [max-age] => -1
        )

    [#children] => 
    [#render_children] => 1
)
```

What can I do to print out first, second, third separately?

How can I access this array within a Drupal Twig Template? I have tried a bunch of different ways but I am confused by the #.